# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following code in my index view

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
 {
   Session["FullName"] = search;

   var dbsenderPostal = (from a in db.TblCUSTOMER_PROFILE
                                where a.FullName == search
                                select a.PostalAddress).ToArray();

   Session["PostalAddress"] = dbsenderPostal;

   if (searchBy == "XXX")
        {
            return View(db.TblCUSTOMER_PROFILE.Where(senders => 
            senders.GeneratedCode == search || search == null).ToList());
        }
        else
        {

            return View(db.TblCUSTOMER_PROFILE.Where(senders => 
            senders.CustomerFullName.StartsWith(search) || search == 
            null).ToList());

        }
 }
```

In my [HttpPost] MorePost view, I am passing data to this 'MorePost' post controller using Sessions with the value pairs. If i add the .Split() method to 'ViewBag.messages2', another error occurs as " 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for split ". This is from further research online to solve this proble. Please am i doing anything wrong with my LINQ query to ViewBag which is passing data to the object name 'sentprint'. I am able to retrieve the data from the LINQ query as '**P.O.Box AX 33 Miami**'. I have also tried using 'TempData'. 
 like this TempData["PostalAddress"].
I did try other approaches which gives other errors as "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery' to 'string' ". Sorry I am new to LINQ query. Thanks in Advance.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult MorePost(string Itemn)
  {
    TblSENDERSINFORMATION sentprint = new TblSENDERSINFORMATION();

        ViewBag.messages = Session["FullName"];

        sentprint.NameOfSender = ViewBag.messages;

        ViewBag.messages2 = Session["PostalAddress"];

        sentprint.PostalAddress = ViewBag.messages2;  //Error found here

        sentprint.Item = Itemn;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the linq query itself, let me explain why

In your query you are getting an array of strings due this

> .ToArray()

even if it is only one item, it is an array of strings containing one item

```
  var dbsenderPostal = (from a in db.TblCUSTOMER_PROFILE
                                where a.FullName == search
                                select a.PostalAddress).ToArray();
```

So your solution is pretty simple, just change the **ToArray()** by **FirstOrDefault()**, this way you will get only one string item always (like a top 1 but slightly different)

So your query should look like this

```
  var dbsenderPostal = (from a in db.TblCUSTOMER_PROFILE
                                where a.FullName == search
                                select a.PostalAddress).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now your session variable will be a string.

**In this case you have to understand better linq and also generics.**

Comment: This answer is correct, I would just add that FirstOrDefault() Method name is confusing cause if the query return no result you will get a null not a Default value like an empty string. So you might need to handle it if the postal address can't be null somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Dexter good to know it worked for you, please mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

this an example of why you shouldn't use var, until you know what you are doing.

Use strong type, unless you are able to read the code, in soft type.

```
var dbsenderPostal = (from a in db.TblCUSTOMER_PROFILE
                                where a.FullName == search
                                select a.PostalAddress).ToArray();
```

literally means:

```
string[] dbsenderPostal = (from a in db.TblCUSTOMER_PROFILE
                                where a.FullName == search
                                select a.PostalAddress).ToArray();
```

Therefore:

```
ViewBag.messages2 = Session["PostalAddress"];
sentprint.PostalAddress = ViewBag.messages2
```

this makes no sense, you are literally trying to put a string[] into a string.